# Next page is getting rendered over the previous one in Reactjs, How to render it separately?

Tags: reactjs, react-routing

When i try to render the next page using react routing, it is getting rendered over the previous page, i want a separate page after render as that in  tag in HTML, please help, below is my code snippet.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import NextPage from './Components/NextPage';
import NextPages from './Components/NextPages';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component{
  state = {
    name:""
  }

  inputOnClick = (event) =>{
    this.setState({name:event.target.value});
  }

  render(){    
    return(
      <div className = "App">
        <Router>
          <Link to = "/NextPage">Click here</Link>
          <br/>
          <Link to = "/NextPages">Click here2</Link>
          <Switch>
          <Route exact path = "/NextPage" render = {(props)=><NextPage Name={this.state.name}/>} />
          <Route exact path = "/NextPages" render = {(props)=><NextPages Name={this.state.name}/>} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
        <br/>
        <input value = {this.state.name} onChange ={this.inputOnClick}></input>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you please explain it more , its confusing what you actually want.

Comment: @Shivam Shah what are you trying to do? explain little more

Comment: @AyushiKeshri what i meant is that if i click to go to next page, that next page is rendering below the previous page. it is not rendering separately as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Put the routes section in index.js and link to section in app.js, it will help to goto next page

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking like this?

Here both components are independent with each other because components replaces to other based on routing(`react-router-dom`).

https://codesandbox.io/s/routing-z5fbg

demo [Live](https://z5fbg.csb.app/)